# How do I get a discord bot send a DM to someone I ping?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm fairly new coding and thought I'd take a shot at making a discord bot. So far it's been easy enough to follow and I've started to try to make commands for my bot. But I can't figure out how to get my bot to DM a person I ping ex. !warn @person (reason). I've tried looking it up and can't find out how.

```
[Command("warn")]
[RequireUserPermission(GuildPermission.KickMembers, ErrorMessage = "You don't have the persmission ''warn_member''!")]
public async Task WarnMember(IGuildUser user = null, [Remainder] string reason = null)
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        await ReplyAsync("Please Specify A User"); return;
    }
    if (reason == null) reason = "Not Specified";
```

this is where I'm trying to send the DM but it sends it to the person who ran the command and not who I pinged

```
await Context.User.SendMessageAsync("You have been warned for " + reason);

var EmbedBuilder = new EmbedBuilder()
    .WithDescription($":white_check_mark: {user.Mention} was warned\n**Reason **{reason}")
    .WithFooter(footer =>
    {
         footer
         .WithText("User Warn Log");
               
    });
    Embed embed = EmbedBuilder.Build();
    await ReplyAsync(embed: embed);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context.User always refers to the user who is executing the command. To send a message to the person mentioned in the command, you need to call the SendMessageAsync() function on your user argument.

```cs
await user.SendMessageAsync(...)
```

Keep in mind that users can have direct messages disabled for the server your bot is in, this could result in an exception.